# How to save the mobile number format in csv

Tags: excel, csv

I need to save the mobile number format in csv file to send as input to my automation script.
I am unable to save the format as +919001230981.

How we can save this format.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: no error, after close and open it is converting into 913+E1 format

Answer (score 0):

- Enter the number as it is in a cell.
- Select the cell and press `Ctrl + 1`
- in Custom tab, select the format as `+0`

This should work for you. If so , apply the same formatting to all cells in that column

Comment: it worked for that moment but, next time when i opened, the number is showing with E format

Comment: hi thanks for reply, it worked for that moment after open it is as it is like earlier, i think the problem is that, i saved the file in csv format and opening in excel, because of this it is not saved the format we selected

Comment: @SaradaAkurathi may be you should save in xls for formatting it

Comment: but for automation work we need to save it in csv files

Comment: @SaradaAkurathi How do you generate the csv as part of that automation? you use any scripting?

Comment: no, i am not generating, i am creating my self csv and reading csv in automation script, while creating manually the csv, it is to give the details by open in Excel, but as the data as mobile number, it is not saved properly. Now, i open the csv in one of the editor and updating the details

Comment: @SaradaAkurathi I did the same as above, saved the sheet, closed and opened it and i am not seeing any issues. may be you are doing something different from the above answer